# Fluent Validation - Email Validation fails if email has underscore - Clarified

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have been using FluentValidation and I love it. Today however i got a problem where an user typed a email address with underscore in the domain name for example: test@unit_test.com

It seems like the email validation does not accept underscore at all which is causing trouble.

I would like to know if anyway that uses fluentvalidation had this problem before and how did you guys fix it.

Many thanks

**EDIT: As it turns out, its not a bug with Fluent Validation as domain names are not supposed to have _. Many thanks for the comments guys and sorry as I got confused for a while and thought it was allowed to have _**

Ademar

Comment: Any way of overriding the default, Id presume, Regex?

Comment: Thanks brumScouse, and yes, it would work, just want to know if it is a known issue and what are the adopted solutions. Do you use fluentvalidation?

Comment: yes, fluent [validation][1] fails underscore in domain address, you should write and override your own validator. here is a great sample http://www.robertgray.net.au/posts/building-your-own-custom-fluentvalidation-validator#.U2o5R_mSwiQ

Comment: Wouldn't you like to keep the proper validation rules in place? The underscore character is not valid in the domain portion of an email address, since it is intended to be used as a [hostname](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname).

Comment: Thanks @Ehsan, yeah I have extended fluent validation quite a bit and I am familiar with the process. Thanks anyway. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks @BrianR.Mullin, thanks, you are right, and I feel very stupid now as for a moment i thought it was allowed to have _ in the domain part. Thanks